# Run menu is empty in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I retrieve?

Generally I know it is possible using notepad++ to have some advance options in running like run in chrome etc.

However when I go to the Run tab the only option I have is the `Run F5` and nothing else. How can I have the other options?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "How can I have the other options?"

Comment: @Paul I don't have the option i.e. for chrome run Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R How can I insert it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is mine.

1. Close Notepad++
2. Edit or create `shortcut.xml` file in the
   `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\` directory.
3. Start Notepad++

You should be able to see shortcuts in run menu.

```xml
<NotepadPlus>
    <InternalCommands />
    <Macros>
        <Macro name="Trim Trailing and save" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="83">
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="42024" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41006" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
    </Macros>
    <UserDefinedCommands>
        <Command name="Launch in Firefox" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="88">firefox &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
        <Command name="Launch in IE" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="73">iexplore &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
        <Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">chrome &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
        <Command name="Launch in Safari" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="70">safari &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
        <Command name="Get php help" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="112">http://www.php.net/%20$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
        <Command name="Google Search" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="113">http://www.google.com/search?q=$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
        <Command name="Wikipedia Search" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="114">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
        <Command name="Open file" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="116">$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe $(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
        <Command name="Open in another instance" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="117">$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe $(CURRENT_WORD) -nosession -multiInst</Command>
        <Command name="Open containing folder" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">explorer $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)</Command>
        <Command name="Open current dir cmd" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">cmd /K cd /d $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)</Command>
        <Command name="Send via Outlook" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="79">outlook /a &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
    </UserDefinedCommands>
    <PluginCommands />
    <ScintillaKeys />
</NotepadPlus>
```